# Prevent JSHint warning that 'functionName is defined but never used'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint, jshint

I have just started using JSHint (through the Sublime-Linter package for Sublime Text 2). I would like to suppress its warnings regarding functions that are used before they are defined, as I see no problem with using function definitions like this. For example, the following code generates warnings:

```
(function($){ 

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      formValidationSetup();
      refreshErrorMessages();
    });

    function formValidationSetup()
    {

    }

    function refreshErrorMessages()
    {

    }

})(jQuery);
```

The warnings:

> 1. formValidationSetup is defined but never used
> 2. refreshErrorMessages is defined but never used

I've tried setting *undef* to *false* in the JSHint options, but I'm still getting these errors. Is there another option I should be setting? Form the [JSLint docs](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options) for *undef*:

> true if variables and functions need not be declared before used. This
>   is not available in strict mode.

Comment: You should take that as a hint to define the functions before the event. Not that it matters technically, but it's easier to understand the code that way.

Comment: Surely that's just a matter of preference. I find it easier to understand like this as there is less code.

Comment: How is there more code if you just move the function definitions to the top?

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstood you. You're right. Same amount of code. Just more logical to me to have the initialiser first.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To avoid the warning

> defined but never used

in jslint in your javascript add comments like:

```
 /*exported formValidationSetup, refreshErrorMessages */
```

In jshint and jslint you can set the unused option to false:

```
 /*jshint unused:false*/
```

See [Options](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options)

Comment: What about all the other unused variables? `unused:false` from my understanding will cause it to ignore _all_ unused behaviour. I don't think this is what's trying to be achieved.

Comment: `// jshint ignore:line` will ignore that one line.

Comment: unused is not valid in jslint

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem with `should` and `expect` in Chai tests.  I ended up with this pattern:

```
'use strict';

var request = require('supertest');
var should = require('chai').should();  // jshint ignore:line
var expect = require('chai').expect;    // jshint ignore:line

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
var appPromise = require('./index');

describe('GET /r_u_up', function() {

  it('respond with 204', function(done) {
    appPromise.then(function(app) {
      request(app)
      .get('/r_u_up')
      .expect(204, done);
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Superior answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use

```
"unused": false,
```

in your .jshintrc

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, adding `'use strict';` inside the IIFE suppresses the error. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 3):

A better way not touching the `Gruntfile.js` in a typical Yoeman setup is to edit the `.jshintrc` file (a hidden file in Unix system). And update the content as the following:

```
{
  "curly": true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "immed": true,
  "latedef": true,
  "newcap": true,
  "noarg": true,
  "sub": true,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": false, // the change is here
  "boss": true,
  "eqnull": true,
  "node": true
}
```

set the `"unused"` to `false`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider formatting code elements in your answer using indented code blocks or preformatted text: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use the 'latedef' option