# jshint "function" is defined but never used or how to declare a function

Tags: javascript, function, jshint

im getting the jshint notification 
    line 1 col 10  'popUp' is defined but never used.

the js looks like that:

```
function popUp(e, element) {
    do.something();
};
```

it would be easy to change the jshint config to

```
/* jshint unused:false */
```

but i want to see if there are other variables which arent used?

do i have to improve my function declartion or is it jshint?

edit

i boiled it down to two failures, these are the functions who are called  in the html file onmousemove or mouseover...

Comment: Why do you have a function that you aren't using?

Comment: actually i'm using them? thats whats funny about it?

Comment: Could you share more code then? You might have a typo or something similar. JSHint is rarely wrong in these cases.

Comment: Define before use perhaps.

Comment: @AlexK. the script loads at the end of html but the call is in the html, thiscould be a problem... thanks

Comment: See answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607289/prevent-jshint-warning-that-functionname-is-defined-but-never-used

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763987/jshint-myfunction-is-defined-but-never-used for that matter. This seems to be a popular question to make duplicates for