# Silence JSHint when a specific

Tags: node.js, express, jshint

Consider the following standard Express function:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}
```

The following warning is displayed:

> 'next' is defined but never used. - W098

I know I can disable *all warnings*, but that's not what I want. What I need is to silence JSHint only for a specific parameter ('next' in the snippet above.)

I haven't seen any clear answers to this seemingly common issue. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent JSHint warning that 'functionName is defined but never used'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607289/prevent-jshint-warning-that-functionname-is-defined-but-never-used)

Comment: I'm afraid that what you're asking is not possible. Essentially you can add `unused: vars` in your `.jshintrc` or in your file, but I don't think you can disable it only for a specific parameter.

Comment: "*[...] this seemingly common issue.*" This is actually rather unusual with Express requiring 4 named parameters to recognize error handlers. In most cases, the `length` of a function isn't significant and removing the additional parameter to satisfy the warning wouldn't affect how the application operates.

Comment: The [2nd answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13028466) to the question Paolo linked to is probably the closest possible -- disable the `unused` warning within that `function`. JSHint's ["inline configuration" comments](http://jshint.com/docs/) "*are function scoped meaning that if you put them inside a function they will affect only this function's code.*"

Comment: Jonathan, Express 4 *requires* an arity of 4 for error handling: "Error-handling middleware is defined just like regular middleware, except that must be defined with an arity of 4 (that is the signature (err, req, res, next))". See http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling

Answer (score 3):

In this case you can do something like below

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        /*jshint unused: vars*/
        var foo;

        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}
```

Now `jshint` will not cry about `next`, though it will still warn about `foo` being defined but not used.

Importantly, This suppression will be bound to scope of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible!

If you are using the default setup of JSHint, the accepted answer on this thread is your answer too:
[Is there a way to suppress JSHint warning for one given line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977661/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-jshint-warning-for-one-given-line)
It shows how to use comments to conditionally ignore specific errors/warnings from being thrown in JSHint.

If you are using a build tool like Gulp or Grunt, you can add this to your options in your plugin's task configuration. For example, with Grunt:
See section "Ignoring specific warnings" on https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/blob/master/README.md.

Hope this helps!

Comment: While not exactly what I was looking for, adding "// jshint ignore:line" after the offending line silences the warning. It may swallow other warnings, but in my case it doesn't, so it works fine.